# Count number of summands?

Tags: expression-manipulation, expression-test

Consider

```
fun = a+b+c+d/e
```

If we want to get the number of summands, we can use `Length[fun]`, which properly gives `5` in this case. However, if `fun` contains only a single term

```
fun = d/e
```

Then applying `Length[fun]` gives `2` since now it actually counts the number of terms in the multiplication instead of summation.

Therefore, `Length` is rather a hack than an actually reliable function to get the number of summands. Is there an efficient function that returns the number of summands reliably?

Comment: How complicated are these expressions? Will there ever be nested summands, like `Cos[a + b] + Sin[c + d]`? And in this case, is the answer 2?

Comment: @march Yes, and yes.

Comment: Also, should expressions like `(a + b)^2` be treated as having length 1 or length 3? (i.e should the expressions be expanded as much as possible  before calculating a length?)

Comment: @march Yes, we better assume that we want to count `fun//Expand`. Otherwise the summand counting function will probably get really slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best thing I can come up with is

```
cntSummands[expr_]:=If[Head[expr]===Plus,Length[expr],If[expr === 0, 0, 1]]
```

but this sounds like a terrible workaround. I am sure there are better ways?

Comment: Frankly, that doesn't seem to bad to me. I would just add an Expand@ before expr on the right hand side.