# How to remove parentheses from algebraic expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation

Suppose I have an expression like $x+x+y(x+y(x+y))$. I used `Simplify` command and get $y^3+x(2+y+y^2)$. How to remove parentheses
to get every summand explicitly?
$$y^3+2x+xy+xy^2$$

Comment: use `Expand` instead

Comment: @garej, thanks, it worked! Is there a way to count the number of summands?

Comment: of course, i.e. [101119](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101119/count-number-of-summands)

Comment: @garej, what `@` means? You deleted that comment? The `cntSummands` worked, thanks

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616

Comment: @Glinka, [`@`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prefix.html) means very basic thing in MMA. You may use key `F1` with term in question to get reference.

Comment: You could use `Length[Apply[List, Expand[x + x + y (x + y (x + y))]]]`.  Thiw works because after expansion of a polynomial, Plus is the head and the terms are the next level leaves.  Apply makes this a list of terms.